# Ember.Select didInsertElement failing with undefined content

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to dynamically set the contentBinding of an Ember.Select. The content is loaded from an ajax call. `didInsertElement` is being called on the Select before the data is returned from the ajax call. I then get an error:

Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'length' on an undefined object.

The data is eventually loaded and populates, but the initial error terminates the calling of `didInsertElement` for any subsequent Ember.Selects on the page.

I'm using the didInsertElement method to setup [chosen.js](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen). Because the didInsertElement calls never run, the plugin isn't setup correctly.

Any thoughts on whether this is an ember bug or am I misunderstanding something?

EDIT

The error happens on a standard Ember.Select view:

```
Ember.Select prompt="Select child" class="input-medium search" selectionBinding=controller.studentFilter contentBinding=controller.students optionValuePath=content.id optionLabelPath=content.name
```

controller.students is a binding to data that is loaded via an ajax call.

This stops any further processing of didInsertElement and it never calls the instance I need, which occurs later in the DOM and looks like:

```
FP.ChosenMultipleSelect = Em.Select.extend
    attributeBindings: [ 'multiple' ]

    didInsertElement: ->
        @._super()
        @.$().chosen().change( (evt, data) =>
          if data.selected
            @get('controller.selectedStudents').pushObject(data.selected)
          if data.deselected
            remaining = @get('controller.selectedStudents').reject( (s) ->
              s is data.deselected
            )
        )

    selectionChanged: (->
        @.$().trigger('liszt:updated')
    ).observes('selection')
```

The error occurs at:

```
  viewCollection.forEach(function(v) {
    v.transitionTo('inDOM');
    v.propertyDidChange('element');
    v.triggerRecursively('didInsertElement'); <<<<<<<<HERE ember.js line 17423
  });
```

thanks,

Martin

Environment:

```
DEBUG: ------------------------------- ember.js:349
DEBUG: Ember.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 ember.js:349
DEBUG: Handlebars.VERSION : 1.0.0-rc.3 ember.js:349
DEBUG: jQuery.VERSION : 1.8.3 ember.js:349
DEBUG: ----------------------------
```

Stack:

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Cannot call get with 'length' on an undefined object. ember.js:52
Ember.assert ember.js:52
get ember.js:1996
Ember.Select.Ember.View.extend._changeSingle ember.js:22287
Ember.Select.Ember.View.extend._change ember.js:22238
Ember.Select.Ember.View.extend._triggerChange ember.js:22279
sendEvent ember.js:2432
Ember.Evented.Ember.Mixin.create.trigger ember.js:10398
Ember.CoreView.Ember.Object.extend.trigger ember.js:14348
superWrapper ember.js:1044
Ember.View.Ember.CoreView.extend.triggerRecursively ember.js:15842
superWrapper ember.js:1044
get ember.js:17424
Ember.EnumerableUtils.forEach ember.js:1526
ViewCollection.forEach ember.js:14440
insertViewCollection ember.js:17421
Ember.merge.ensureChildrenAreInDOM ember.js:17407
Ember.ContainerView.Ember.View.extend._ensureChildrenAreInDOM
```

Comment: Could you post your `didInsertElement` code?

Comment: Code inserted, but I don't think the `didInsertElement` function is relevant as it never gets called. It seems that any Select without content fails.

Comment: You get that error because the content of your select is not bound, you should bind it to an empty array `Ember.A()` and fill that array through ajax.

Comment: Thanks, will give that a go. Interestingly, I just found that in the `_changeMultiple` method of Ember.select there is an explicit return `if (!content){ return; }` whereas `_changeSingle` has no such statement. Seems strange that the behaviour is different.